# Envío de Datos Formulario HTML, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día, requiero de su apoyo en esta situación. No puedo enviar datos a la base de datos en MySql a traves de un formulario en HTML con PHP.

CONFIG.PHP: https://gist.github.com/luisdavid919/32ccde0982752e8f42bcccb1f2645856

INSERT.PHP: https://gist.github.com/luisdavid919/8068a439bfeec56d689a102dda91a102

TRABAJO.PHP (FORMULARIO HTML): https://gist.github.com/luisdavid919/ae87c988fcc23a4f4d3ba11e274b2fe7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, además de los archivos podrías adjuntar la captura con el error ? Gracias !

Comment: Estimado Juanjoo Tocino, no me da ningun error pero no inserta nada en la base de datos, agradecería tu apoyo bastante. Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe estar en la pregunta ya que los links pueden perderse.

Answer (score 1):

El problema puede estar en el insert.php. Usa $_POST para acceder a la información enviada desde el formulario trabajo.php

```
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$hora = $_POST["hora"];
//...

$sql = "INSERT INTO worklist (fecha,hora,puerta,guardia,id,yesno,pas1,id1,pas2,id2,pas3,id3,trabajador,jefe,destino,tax,motivo) VALUES ('$fecha', '$hora','$puerta','$guardia','$id','$yesno','$pas1','$id1','$pas2','$id2','$pas3','$id3', '$trabajador','$jefe','$destino','$tax','$motivo');";
```

Comment: Estimado Fernando, ya lo he realizado pero sigue sin funcionar. He actualizado el "insert.php" en el gist

Answer (score 0):

Debes capturar primero todas la variables que llegan por `POST`, y luego enviarlas en el query, asi:

```
$folio =$_POST['folio'];
$fecha =$_POST['fecha'];
hora =$_POST['hora'];
$puerta =$_POST['puerta'];
$guardia =$_POST['guardia'];
$id =$_POST['id'];
$yesno =$_POST['yesno'];
$pas1 =$_POST['pas1'];
$id1 =$_POST['id1'];
$pas2 =$_POST['pas2'];
$id2 =$_POST['id2'];
$pas3 =$_POST['pas3'];
$id3 =$_POST['id3'];
$trabajador =$_POST['trabajador'];
$jefe =$_POST['jefe'];
$destino =$_POST['destino'];
$tax =$_POST['tax'];
$motivo =$_POST['motivo'];
```

espero te sirva xD... **ReNiceCode...**

Comment: Estimado, he hecho tal como indicas pero sigue sin funcionar. He actualizado el gist de "insert.php.

Comment: y que error te manda ?

Comment: No inserta en la base de datos

Comment: Ya probaste la consulta en la base de datos directamente ? es decir con valores puesto, ademas noto que en tu query no hay "WHERE" deberias ponerlo para que no te agregre en todas las filas

Comment: por otro lado has un echo de todas la variables que estan llegando para saber que datos estan trayendo, ya que tambien cabe de que un valor este llegando null y la BD no lo permita null

Comment: Habra posibilidad de que pueda contactarte por un medio más particular?

Comment: Bro, edita tu pregunta y pon la estrucura de la base de datos  yo miro a ver que pueda estar fallando

Comment: Listo, he subido la imagen de la BD

Comment: imagen no bro, tengo algun problema y no puedo ver las imgenes que se suben aqui